# Как сделать дробное значение ID в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть таблица `pdfs`: 
`id, link, creator_id, created_at, updated_at`.

Возникла задача сделать так, чтобы PDF файлы можно было редактировать. Хранение данных, из которых идет генерация - отдельный вопрос и он уже реализован. Вопрос лишь в том, что данная структура предполагает небольшое дерево.

К примеру, если за основу нового файла взят PDF с `id = 5`, то должен сгенерироваться PDF с id 5.1, но я не понимаю, как в таком случае построить БД? Т.е. если оставить так, как сейчас есть,  но добавить поле `parent_id`, которое ссылается на `id` этой таблицы, то id PDF'a будет все равно уже 6, а не 5.1.

Какие есть выходы из данной ситуации?

P.S. проект пишется на Laravel, поэтому ставлю тэги laravel и php.

Comment: добавить колонки `parentId` и `version`. Ну будет `id`=6. Вам то какая разница?

Comment: @ArchDemon вопрос в инкрементировании `version`. Т.е. перед каждым добавлением я должен смотреть, какая последняя версия у PDF и инкрементить её в коде?

Comment: В принципе достаточно добавить колонку `parentId`. Самую свежую версию можно брать по дате редактирования или создания

Comment: Вам нужна реализация **Materialized Path**. В интернете куча примеров

Answer (score 0):

Добавить колонку number, уникальный, автоинкремент. Всё будет просиходить само.
Внешний ключ делаем составным из id и number, через точку и вы получите то что вам нужно.

Если же вам всё же не нужно добавлять колонки, то вы совершенно спокойно можете изменить тип колонки id и хранить в ней числа с плавающей точкой, но инкрементировать придётся через ларавел